# Can my relative still ride a bike despite having RSI

Tags: mountain-bike

My relative has RSI, and encounters wrist pain from fairly minor activities involving use of hands. Is there anything that could be recommended so they could still enjoy cycling despite having RSI?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: [Repetitive Strain Injury](https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/repetitive-strain-injury-rsi/)

Answer (score 2):

I'll note that health and medical advice is generally off-topic here, but the bicycle configuration could have a strong bearing on how your relative manages.

Generally speaking an upright posture, on a "city bike", will place less stress on the hands and arms than a racier road bike or mountain bike.

And some recumbent configurations, especially of the tricycle variety, are also less stressful to the hands and arms.

But it's up to your relative, in consultation with his doctor and a knowledgeable bike fitter, to decide what is suitable.

Comment: Also, using a coaster brake (where you brake by pushing the pedals backwards) as the main break instead of a hand-operated brake can help. (this comment is not enough for a full answer, so perhaps you can just add that to your suggestions?)

Comment: @StephanMatthiesen Good point, but I'd prefer putting the front brake on the lever of the uninjured hand, and use the coaster as the safety backup: Coaster brakes have excellent robustness, providing a fail-safe backup, but they do not provide good stopping power and can easily overheat on a descent. With a hand brake for normal operation and a coaster brake for backup, you get the best of both.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica You're right about the stopping power of coaster brakes. I guess it depends on the kind of cycling and the environment; I was thinking Dutch-style urban utility cycling where many people use the coaster brake as the main brake and it's totally sufficient for the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

This is more an "indirect" answer, as the best solution for your relative really depends on the individual details and preferences.

There are cycling organisations where people with medical conditions and disabilities come together, and perhaps the best advice is to get in touch with one in your country. They may have local groups where you can go and hear other's experiences and also try out adapted bikes. They may also be able to give better advice than your average doctor who may not know much about cycling.

Experience in these groups show that people with all sorts of different conditions do cycle and enjoy it very much, so there's a really good chance that your relative will be able to find a solution too.

In the UK, there is "Wheels for Wellbeing" that do a lot of good work i this respect (https://wheelsforwellbeing.org.uk).